# Lenovo Y50-70 screen replacement

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair, laptop-display

I want to replace my default Lenovo Y50 screen because it is damaged. I have bought already two different screens to replace it but neither of their connectors work.

This: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BqVuCKew1E makes it look so easy, and I was following recommendations for screens to get online. How can I find a screen that will have the right connector?

Screens I have tried:

- LP156WF4(SP)(D1)
- B156HAN01.2

Will supply pictures when I am home from work.

Comment: Is there a model number on the screen that is broken?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Super User is not a place to discuss hardware repair questions. Please don't post such questions as they may be negatively received.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Lenovo support and ask for the correct display part number for your specific model (which was not supplied).  There are many Y50-70 displays, including a 4K variant.  A Lenovo customer service rep will guide you to provide your proper model number, so that they can provide the proper display part number.